# Why does the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard run when trying to open a Visual Studio 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Here are the details in case it helps:

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium (Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel)

Here is the header from the Visual Studio Solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
...
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

After taking advice from DevinB (see first comment) I found the following changes had been made by the upgrade:

- Updated .net framework from 3.5 to 4.0
- Updated "Old Tools Version" from 3.5 to 4.0
- Downgraded Unit Test framework from 10.1 to 10

Comment: The projects themselves might be the wrong version. When you run the conversion wizard, it should tell you what files were changed, and what it had to do to them. You DO NOT have to save. Running the conversion wizard is completely cancelable.

Comment: Thanks for that... it was useful.  I'm going to add my findings so far to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing service pack 1 of Visual Studio 2010 solved my problem.  This is how I figured that out:

I took advice from DevinB (see first comment on question) by running the upgrade and comparing the files with the original to see what changed.  I found the following changes had been made by the upgrade:

- Updated .net framework from 3.5 to 4.0
- Updated "Old Tools Version" from 3.5 to 4.0
- Downgraded Unit Test framework from 10.1 to 10

From this I guessed that the problem is that I need to upgrade Visual Studio with Service Pack 1.